# useGetAllFavQuery is not a function

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

There is an API in which I either get a list of favorites for the user, or remove something from this list, or add:

```
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import {
  arrayRemove,
  arrayUnion,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { userConverter } from "../converter/userConverter";
import { firestore } from "../firebase";

export const favApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  reducerPath: "favApi",
  tagTypes: ["Favourite"],
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllFav: builder.query({
      async queryFn(email) {
        try {
          if (!email) {
            return { data: [] };
          }
          const userLink = doc(firestore, "users", email).withConverter(
            userConverter
          );
          const user = await getDoc(userLink);

          const userData = user.data();
          if (userData) {
            return { data: userData.favourite };
          }
          return { data: [] };
        } catch (err) {
          return { error: err };
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ["Favourite"],
    }),
    addToFav: builder.mutation({
      async queryFn(email, item) {
        try {
          if (!email) {
            return { data: [] };
          }
          const userLink = doc(firestore, "users", email).withConverter(
            userConverter
          );

          await updateDoc(userLink, {
            favourite: arrayUnion(item),
          });
          return { data: item };
        } catch (err) {
          return { error: err };
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ["Favourite"],
    }),
    removeFromeFav: builder.mutation({
      async queryFn(email, item) {
        try {
          if (!email) {
            return { data: [] };
          }
          const userLink = doc(firestore, "users", email).withConverter(
            userConverter
          );

          await updateDoc(userLink, {
            favourite: arrayRemove(item),
          });
          return { data: item };
        } catch (err) {
          return { error: err };
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ["Favourite"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetAllFavQuery,
  useAddToFavMutation,
  useRemoveFromeFavMutation,
} = favApi;
```

But when requesting a list of favorites for a user I get an error
*api_favApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.useGetAllFavQuery) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , *api_favApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.useGetAllFavQuery) is not a function

Hook where I import created endpoints from api:

```
import {
  useAddToFavMutation,
  useGetAllFavQuery,
  useRemoveFromFavMutation,
} from "../api/favApi";
import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";

export const useFav = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const { data: favourites = [] } = useGetAllFavQuery(user?.email);

  const [addFav, addRes] = useAddToFavMutation();
  const [removeFav, removeRes] = useRemoveFromFavMutation();

  const isItemFav = (id) => favourites.some((item) => item.id === id);

  const addToFav = async (data) => {
    await addFav({ email: user?.email, item: data });
  };

  const removeFromFav = async (data) => {
    await removeFav({ email: user?.email, item: data });
  };

  return {
    isFav: isItemFav,
    isDisabled: addRes.isLoading || removeRes.isLoading,
    addToFav,
    removeFromFav,
  };
};
```

My store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { booksApi } from "../api/booksApi";
import { favApi } from "../api/favApi";
import { listenerMiddleware } from "./middlewares/userMiddleware";
import userReducer from "./reducers/userSlice";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  [booksApi.reducerPath]: booksApi.reducer,
  [favApi.reducerPath]: favApi.reducer,
  userReducer,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }).concat(
      booksApi.middleware,
      favApi.middleware,
      listenerMiddleware.middleware
    ),
});
```

The line where I make the request:

```
  const { data: favourites = [] } = useGetAllFavQuery(user?.email);
```

I suspect that the problem is that not functions are exported from the api, but constants with type any, but I don’t know how to fix this and what is the reason for this.

Edit: i`ve tried also to console.log useGetAllFavQuery function, and it logs 'undefined' in console

Comment: You have two obvious problems here: 1. Is `combineReducers` is deprecated and you should not use it. 2. It's not recommended to have more then one `createApi` call, you should use api.injectEndpoints and api.enhanceEndpoints.

Comment: But what should I do if I want to have 2 different APIs: one for getting books at a specific url, the other for interacting with the firebase database? As far as I know, I don't need baseQuery when working with firebase, only the async queryFn functions, so I'd like to separate them into 2 different files. Can I leave them in different files?

Comment: As heard it may work, but you need different `reducerPath` for each and you should register middleware for each (you are actually doing this) so should be ok, just not recommended...

Comment: about webpack error, try remove node_modules and package.lock

Comment: this impossible to debug without repo...